# How to change only the from and to values after post action is done in price slider while pagination links were clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, pagination

Actually I'm doing filtering option with pagination.And in that I use checkbox and price slider for performing filters.

I wrote code for the checkbox option as when pagination links were clicked it must checked which checkboxes were clicked..

And coding is here,

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['key'])){
 $key_val = $_REQUEST['key'];
 if(in_array($amn->ht_amenity_id, $key_val)){
                                        ?>
    <label>
    <input class="i-check iCheck-helper" name="{{$keys[$i]}}" type="checkbox" value="{{$amn->ht_amenity_id}}" checked="checked" />{{$amn->ht_amenity_name}}
<?php
    echo "<br/><br/>";
        }
 else{
?>
    <label>
    <input class="i-check iCheck-helper" name="{{$keys[$i]}}" type="checkbox" value="{{$amn->ht_amenity_id}}" />{{$amn->ht_amenity_name}}
<?php
    echo "<br/><br/>";
}}
?>
```

It works for me..

Here is My code for price slider,

```
<li>
    <h5 class="booking-filters-title">Price</h5>
    <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['from']) && isset($_REQUEST['to'])){
    $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
    $to = $_REQUEST['to'];
    echo $from;exit;
    ?>
        <input type="text" id="price-slider" value="$from;$to">
    <?php
    }
    else{
    ?>
    <input type="text" id="price-slider">
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
</li>
```

I tried like this way..But it didn't work for me..

When my pagination links were clicks it pass all the values through the URL.And also the results were given as per my filters.

But the price slider does not change after my pagination links were clicked..

And here is my controller code,

```
$query = "SELECT `h`.*,".$countquery.",".$minquery." FROM `abserve_hotels` as `h`";

        $query1 = DB::select($query.$sqlCond);
        // $perPage = 2;
        $currentPage = Input::get('page', 1) - 1;
        $pagedData = array_slice($query1, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage);
        $query1 =  new Paginator($pagedData, count($query1), $perPage);
        $query1->setPath('hotelresults');
```

And in My view I use `echo $query1->appends($_REQUEST)->render();` like this to call the pagination

Someone help me..
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980373/how-to-use-pagination-in-laravel-5 this could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkbox code is same as it.And my code for price slider is here,

**javascript-Ajax**

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
            var from_num = <?php echo json_encode($from)?>;
            var to_num = <?php echo json_encode($to)?>;
            var from_default = <?php echo json_encode($from_default)?>;
            var to_default = <?php echo json_encode($to_default)?>;

        var sel = "";
        var nme = "";

        function somethingChanged(from_num,to_num,sel,nme) {
            // alert(from_num);
            var sel = $('.i-check:checked').map(function(_, el) {
                        return $(el).val();
                }).get();
            var nme = $('.i-check:checked').map(function() {
                        return $(this).attr("name");
                }).get();

              $.ajax({
                // alert();
                url: 'hotelresults',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    from: from_num,
                    to: to_num,
                    key: sel,
                    name: nme,
                    page:page
                },
                success: function(data) {
                  $('.hotel_list').html(data);
                }
              });
        }

        $("#price-slider").ionRangeSlider({
            from:from_num,
            to:to_num,
            min: from_default,
            max: to_default,
            type: 'double',
            prefix: "$",

            onChange : function (data) {

                var from_num = data.fromNumber;
                var to_num =data.toNumber;
                somethingChanged(from_num,to_num,sel,nme);
            }
        });        

        $( ".iCheck-helper" ).on( "click", function(){
            var price=$("#price-slider").val();

            var myarr = price.split(";");
            var from_num = myarr[0];
            var to_num = myarr[1];

            somethingChanged(from_num,to_num,sel,nme);

        });
    });
```

Here I use `from_default` and `to_default` from database using queries and I pass it here to set the `min` and `max` option.

Before I using this code the results were shown as per post action.

i.e.,If pagination links where clicked, the `min` and `max` values are also changed in my page by setting the posted `min` and `max` value as default price slider minimum and maximum values..

So for this only I use the `from_default` & `to_default` as the price slider minimum and maximum values.

When I change the slider option it pass the values in post action, but the `min` and `max` values are assign to be default values.So it doesn't change.

Only the `from` & `to` values were changed as per my post action.

Thanks,